# Springboot security access per field

Tags: spring, spring-security, field

I would like to make access per field in spring mvc.
For example

I got entity with 3 fields
id,name,description. 
User with ROLE_USER can see only name and user who got ROLE_ADMIN can see name and description. I tried to use 
`@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")` in entity and dto but its only work in service and controller.

I tried to use `@Component` adonation before `@Entity` but it doesnt work.

ps: `prePostEnabled` is configured

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
```

any solutions?

Comment: I need make it per field not per method.
I just wana response only json, wont use thymleaf its not web project

Answer (score 0):

For this propouse a better approach is use the spring security tag if you are using jsp or thymeleaf spring security dialect if you are using thymeleaf.

in the first case you have this maven dependency in your pom

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
    <version>your.version</version>
</dependency>
```

in the second case you have this maven dependency in your pom

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
    <version>your.version</version>
</dependency>
```

the key point hear is that with `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` you are working at method security protection and not at presentation level protection. In other words with your configuration you can protect the your method calling at application level in base of how the Security contect is popolated while for a presentation protection Spring security provide some custom tag for acive this propouse, for thymeleaf you can use the security dialect.

I hope that this can help you

Comment: I need make it per field not per method. I just wana response only json, wont use thymleaf its not web project

Comment: spring security intercept method and url attached to a method, if you want a finegrain security for field you may implements an aspect that in base at your securiy context perform the your srcurity restriction